# Pulseaudio: combining sinks results in having an LFE channel that uses the centre speaker

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

My goal is applying a low pass LADSPA filter on my subwoofer only, which is part of my 5.1 sound system, in Pulseaudio.

I used the following commands:

1. Loading the plugin:

   ```
   pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_low_pass master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_02.0.analog-surround-51 plugin=lowpass_iir_1891 label=lowpass_iir control=86,1
   ```
2. Creating a sink with the filtered LFE channel:

   ```
   pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=remapLFE master=ladspa_low_pass master_channel_map=lfe channel_map=lfe channels=1
   ```
3. Creating a sink with the rest of the channels I don't want to apply the filter to:

   ```
   pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=remap50 master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_02.0.analog-surround-51 channels=5 master_channel_map=front-left,center,front-right,rear-left,rear-right channel_map=front-left,center,front-right,rear-left,rear-right
   ```
4. Combining the two sinks:

   ```
   pacmd load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combine sink_properties=device.description=myCombine slaves=remap50,remapLFE channel_map=front-left,center,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,lfe channels=6
   ```

After all these steps, I can see and test the channels included with each sink individually in Phonon. They are all correct except in case of the sink 'myCombine', where when I test the subwoofer, sound comes from my centre speaker instead.

So, my question is, how do I fix this?

**Edit**: Now as I test it again, it turns out that sound comes out from all channels.

Comment: Can't test this here but IIRC you won't need to remap channels when creating a combined sink, because the sinks are already mapped. What happens if you removed the `channel_map=...` part?

Comment: If I delete that part from the last command, the result is even more messed up because I have the following channels shown in Phonon: front left, front left centre, left centre, front right centre, front right, and rear centre.